# Could I set vc's view becomeFirstResponder by touchesBegan func in storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, touchesbegan

In code, I can use this below method to let `vc`'s `view` `becomeFirstResponder`, and play down the show-up `keyboard`.

> [image]

the code is below:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Could I set this `function` in my storyboard? or there is some way easier for `self.view.endEditing(true)` when click `self.view`?

Because if not do this, I will copy the function upper to almost every `vc`.

Comment: add getsure to your VC in storyboard, and add one function for gesture, inside the gesture add endediting function

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik If do like this, it is almost the same with `override func touchesBegan` method, because the amount of code is as much as it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this somewhere in the code and it would resolve your issue with code duplicating

```
extension UIViewController {
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure tho if it's a good way of doing this, maybe you'd like to rethink the architectural issues of resigning the textfield's responder, regards of what you really need.

Comment: how can I do this in objective-c?

Comment: I mean the extension

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension of UIViewController and then make swizzling methods for touchesBegans and your own customTouchBegans. see an example of swizzling methods for viewWillAppear 
https://www.uraimo.com/2015/10/23/effective-method-swizzling-with-swift/